# Menu deletes all items and position - wordpress bug?

Tags: menus, admin

I just went through one of our sites and updated every plugin and Wordpress to 4.2.2.

After upgrading I was supposed to do some menu changes, but after "successfully" saving the menu every item was cleared from the menu and it's position was reset to nothing..

I then started building the menu all over again, only to realize it kept on happening.

I've tried deactivating every plugins and changing themes to a default one, but the problem persists. Anyone had a similar experience?
This happens to every menu I try editing and also new ones that I create from scratch.

Here's a video of me trying to add some menu items and assigning a position:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9XLyy-Zzbw&feature=youtu.be

Unfortunately I did end up having to restore the site with a backup I took before updating, so I can't link to a live problem..

**EDIT**

Regarding kenno's answer that it might be a case of taxonomy split, I do indeed have a lot of shared terms.

[image: My shared terms]

Is there an easy fix for this, or a way to quickly loop through all terms instead of manually splitting terms one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bad case of taxonomy split introduced in WP 4.2

ref. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/02/16/taxonomy-term-splitting-in-4-2-a-developer-guide/

Solution for this would be to use this plugin to detect and fix the splitting before Updating menus which is a bit buggy in my opinion. Update nav menus will trigger "wp_nav_menu_update_menu_items" function which between split gives new menu 0 sub-items.

https://github.com/jjeaton/wp-find-shared-terms

Comment: I do indeed have a lot of shared terms (which I somehow thought would be no problem under development), but I don't see an easy fix for this. With 774 shared terms how can I split them all easily?

Comment: If you don't use fixed term_ids in any of your theme functions /database and plugins are updated then you should just click the "Split Shared Terms" below the table.(backup is required)

Comment: hmm, I don't have that link below the table. This is the same plugin you linked to, and under Tools->Split Shared Terms or do I need to perform the update to 4.2.2 first?

Comment: Checked the code for the plugin and realized I have to update to 4.2.2 first. Another thing I'm wondering that you might be able to help me out with is if splitting all these terms can do some damage to other areas of the site. I'm using a few very outdated plugins like a customized "Co-Authors Plus" plugin and a few of the plugins listed on make.wordpress.org

Comment: Depends on these plugins, if they have something to do with Terms (which in CoAuthors case not) they could be affected. Usually the outdated plugins are always very dangerous on all aspects.

Comment: I just ran all updates, split the terms and the problem is fixed. Thank you for your excellent help my friend :)